# ERROR 1297: Got temporary error 4010 'Node failure caused abort of transaction' from NDBCLUSTER when importing data

Tags: mysql, errors, mysql-cluster, import

I have the cluster built by one MGM Node and two data/sql nodes

When importing **data** to an `NDB` node the importation crashes returning the following:

```
ndb_2# mysql -u root -p db < data.sql
Enter password:
ERROR 1297 (HY000) at line 214: Got temporary error 4010 'Node failure caused abort of transaction' from NDBCLUSTER
```

Monitoring the other `NDB` node, I could see the data is being well inserted, but at `'n'` records, the first node return the ERROR.

The `ndb_2_out.log` & `ndb_3_out.log` write:

```
WARNING  -- ACK wo/ gcp record (gci: 60138/0) ref: 0fa20004 from: 0fa20004
```

The `ndb_2_error.log` & `ndb_3_error.log` don't write anything.

Before the crash, both nodes have the same records.

I google it but I can't find anything related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reading some forums, the variables that avoids this issue are:

```
MaxBufferedEpochs
TimeBetweenEpochsTimeout
```

This must be configured in `MGMT Node`

```
/var/lib/mysql-cluster/config.ini
```

As we can see in [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-ndbd-definition.html), the default for `MaxBufferedEpochs` is **100**, the default for `TimeBetweenEpochsTimeout` is **4000**, change this for the needed value.